# Fastlane stuck forever when run command fastlane init

Tags: ios, devops, fastlane

I am using fastlane with xcode 9 and 
I got a problem with fastlane (2.95.0). When i run command fastlane init it shows me 4 options to choose. And then i chose option number 4 but it stuck forever. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I got this problem too.

Comment: @Chivorn Do you solution yet?

Comment: I cannot find solution yet

Comment: After waiting about 10 minutes I ended the process with `ctrl` + `c`  and haven't had problems yet. Also uploading from iOS to Testflight still worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue also occurred in my machine once. The problem was with Default Ruby environment. Can you give "gem cleanup" a try and see if that speeds things up for you?

Also, if that doesn't work, can you please try below commands-

```
gem cleanup
gem update -p
rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
gem install fastlane --verbose
```

Comment: Dont know but High Sierra has some problem in writing gems in `usr/local/` . From High Sierra and onwards you cannot `chown` this directory.

Comment: Agreed.! Those who are trying this solution make sure to prefix `sudo` to all the `gem` commands

Answer (score 24):

Use `sudo fastlane init`.
This fixed the issue for me

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12500

Answer (score 0):

The other options is just to move fastlane to your user's folder and make it working without sudo:

https://www.michaelehead.com/2016/02/06/installing-gems-without-sudo.html

After that, uninstall all previous installations of fastlane (it can be from `brew install` and `sudo gem install` simultaneously) and reinstall fastlane with `gem install fastlane -NV` without sudo.

Comment: Thx for your answer, can you explain what `-NV` does ?